# Drag and Drop table rows (asp.net mvc)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

I need some help with integrating drag and drop functionality into my project. I tried many different ways, but everything is unsuccessful. I stopped on using jquery, however I still have the issue make it running.  I will highly appreciate any help.

Here is my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

        #table-1 tr:hover {
    background-color:aqua;
    color:#fff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" id="table-1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th> Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody style="cursor:pointer;">
                <tr id="1"><td><div class="dragitem">1</div></td><td><div class="dragitem">One</div></td><td>some text</td></tr>
        <tr id="2"><td>2</td><td>Two</td><td>some text</td></tr>
        <tr id="3"><td>3</td><td>Three</td><td>some text</td></tr>
        <tr id="4"><td>4</td><td>Four</td><td>some text</td></tr>
        <tr id="5"><td>5</td><td>Five</td><td>some text</td></tr>
        <tr id="6"><td>6</td><td>Six</td><td>some text</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("table-1").sortable();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you want to short whole `table` not `tr` inside `tbody`, so why your code is fail. Use `tbody` selector to short `table` row.

```
$("#table-1 tbody").sortable();
```

Note: You are using id so don't forget to add # .

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table-1 tbody").sortable();
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

#table-1 tr:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table" id="table-1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th> Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="cursor:pointer;">
      <tr id="1">
        <td>
          <div class="dragitem">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="dragitem">One</div>
        </td>
        <td>some text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="2">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>some text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="3">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>some text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="4">
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>some text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="5">
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>some text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="6">
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Six</td>
        <td>some text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why I cant copy the data from insde the table?